# How to set different templates path using zend framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I find the type of device using WURFL.Also i have written plugin to set the template for mobile view. Kindly look on below  code.

```
class ZC_Controller_Plugin_Mobile extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract 
{
    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) { 

    $bootstrap  = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam("bootstrap"); 
    $useragent  = $bootstrap->getResource("useragent");     
    $device     = $useragent->getDevice(); 

    Zend_Registry::set("useragent", $useragent);
    Zend_Registry::set("device", $device);

    /**
     * @todo change this to be Mobile 
     */

    //echo $device->getType() . " is the type of device";

    if($device->getType() == "mobile") { 
        /**
         * Set the layout to be mobile, here we make sure we streamline what is loaded
         * so as to not load things that arent needed.
         */
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->setLayout("mobile");

        /**
         * Here we check to see if a mobile version of the template exists.  if it does then we change the view suffix
         * this allows us to load the mobile view if it exists and the defgault view if it doesnt. 
         */
        $base       = APPLICATION_PATH . "/views/scripts/";
        $mobile     = $base .  $request->getControllerName() . "/" . $request->getActionName() . ".mobile.phtml";

        if(is_readable($mobile)) {
            Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('ViewRenderer')->setViewSuffix('mobile.phtml');      
        } 

    }
}

}
```

Also i have created the two templates under `application/layouts/scripts/` 
1.layout.phtml(Desktop view)
2.mobile.phtml(Mobile view)
When i run index page,I have the view based on type of device.Now file structure is like

```
application/view/scripts/index/
```

1.index.phtml
2.index.mobile.phtml

so far so good,Now I want to separate the view path based on type of device. so that i will have path something like

```
application/view/scripts/index/index.phtml (Desktop view)
application/mobile/view/scripts/index/index.phtml (Mobile view)
```

This will be better when developing site based on view.

Kindly advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Zend_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer::setViewBasePathSpec()`

[API documentation](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/db_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer.html#%5CZend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer)

Comment: Thanks very helpful i tried with $this->bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
            $view = $this->bootstrap->getResource('view');$view->setScriptPath(NULL);
            $view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/mobile/views/scripts/');$html = $view->render($request->getControllerName() . "/" . $request->getActionName() . '.phtml');
            Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getExistingHelper('ViewRenderer')->setViewBasePathSpec($html);